# FULL HTML + CSS of bootstrap navbar (menu)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone have a FULL (HTML + CSS) reference of the bootstrap **navbar** (menu) ?

The thing is that each time am working with a new menu, I struggle with finding the correct node to attain to and exact `css` class to override and so on ...

Whenever you go to bootstrap site you'll not find a full reference :(

Comment: follow- http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: @Priya but there is CSS reference ...

Comment: You can simply add this ready code in your basic html or you can say *within html tags* :)

Comment: I missed the NO, what I really need and am looking for is the css classes structure, names, ... the full reference :) ... bzw your review is meaningless and above all useless.

Answer (score 0):

download the bootstarp4 file from here :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/

go to ->bootstrap-4.4.1-dist\css

open `bootstrap.min.css`

open it with visual studio code  clicks `shift+alt+f` to format it according to css file.

and then click `ctrl+f` put `navbar` there .

you will find all the `navbar` classes there..

Thanks.This is the most precisely i can say.